# Does DPKG support for verifying GPG signature for Debian package files?

Tags: dpkg, deb, gnupg, signature

I am trying to enable the GPG verification in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` by remove `no-debsig` in this configuration file:

```
.# Do not enable debsig-verify by default; since the distribution is not using embedded signatures, debsig-verify would reject all packages.

.# no-debsig
```

Then I tried to download and install some unsigned .deb files to my Ubuntu server but I can install them as normal without any action (reject, warning) after.

So my question is: Assuming I downloaded a .deb file from the internet then I run this file by `dpkg -i` to install it, how to verify whether it is from a trusted source or not? I am using Ubuntu server 16.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, dpkg does not support signature verification. Also No because such signatures are a poor measure of trustworthiness in the scenario you describe.

**Neither dpkg nor apt can decide** if a source is a *trusted source*. As the human, it's *your* job to decide if a source is worthy of your trust or not. There is no magic token-of-trustworthiness that is only issued by the good-internet-elves. (And if there were, how could you tell it wasn't a clever fake? Bad actors can sign files, too)

NEVER add a source to apt that you do not trust. Apt depends upon you to make wise decisions.

**Distros control** the chain-of-trust from upstream source, building and signing packages. That's one reason that a wise choice of distro is important. The right distro has the software you need, so you don't go wandering across the internet (mis-)gauging the trust of all the software you gather from each site

**Apt verifies** that packages from your authorized sources are not corrupted nor substituted during download to you. Apt tracks sources and dependencies. Apt does NOT gauge trustworthiness.

**Dpkg** merely **installs** whatever apt tells it to install, and in the order apt dictates. Dpkg used to use debsigs, a long-disused early signature method. Today, dpkg does all sorts of checking...but on the filesystem and on the package and on it's own functioning.

If you tell dpkg to install a deb full of malware, dpkg will do *exactly what you instructed it to do*. Dpkg is like a toaster - you can misuse a toaster and burn down your house. The dpkg developers believe that folly by the human  --bypassing the protections of human sensibility, distro, and/or apt-- is a human problem, not a dpkg bug.

CONSIDER CAREFULLY adding non-Ubuntu packages. They might break your system. They are *unsupported* here.

Note: debsigs are an early and long-disused signature method built into dpkg. They were superseded long, long ago by distros and apt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Agree with you at all, but in my scenario, I want to prevent the unwanted softwares from the attacker, for example an attacker by some ways have the right to install software to my server using "dpkg -i packagename" so how to prevent this issue if it can do normally?  I think we can enable debsig for this scenario, so dpkg can not install anything. Of course, I will enable debsig after I (an administrator) install all further software on it and then just maintaining. That is my idea, and how about you?

Comment: Well, it's YOUR system, so do what you like with it. Generally, if an attacker can gain sudo and run anything on your system (including dpkg), it's too late - it's time to delete that thoroughly-compromised system and start over. It's also time to consider lessons learned and to rethink your security habits during the reinstall.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers help me a lot.